# Returning the temporary values of a recursion function at base case in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am new to Haskell and am trying to learn by implementing the *Needleman-Wunsch* algorithm.

Right now, I'm building the table and then the algorithm recursively goes backwards taking the optimal letter for a better score. 
However, the base case returns an empty string at the moment.

Here is the code:

```
type AlignmentType = (String, String)
optAlignments :: String -> String -> [AlignmentType]
optAlignments xs ys = optLen (length xs) (length ys)
where
    optLen i j = optTable!!i!!j
    optTable = [[ optEntry i j | j<-[0..]] | i<-[0..] ]

    optEntry :: Int -> Int -> [AlignmentType]
    optEntry _ 0 = []
    optEntry 0 _ = []
    optEntry i j
        | x == y = [([b],[c]) | (b:bs,c:cs) <- optLen (i-1) (j-1)]
        | otherwise = max (optLen i (j-1)) (optLen (i-1) j) --to be fixed

        where 
            x = xs!!(i-1)
            y = ys!!(j-1)
```

So my question is, how can I return the values in `[([b],[c]) | (b:bs,c:cs) <- optLen (i-1) (j-1)]` after the recursion has ended?

Comment: A typical way to pass a value for returning from the base recursion case is to use an 'accumulator' parameter (used heavily in SICP). Think what `fold` does to return the value in the base case. Can you add a parameter to your recursive function that you build out during recursive steps and return in the base case?